# Odd form of controlling derivatves

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In Muscalu, Schlag - Classical and Multilinear Harmonic Analysis (Cambridge Universitv Press 2013), page 299 there is a rather odd estimate for wich I cannot find any justification:

Functions used:
$$\def\supp{\mathop{\rm supp}}\begin{align*}
    \psi & \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R) \\
    \supp \psi & \subset [-2,2] \\
    \psi|_{[-1,1]} & \equiv 1 \\
    \chi & \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R) \\
    \supp \chi & \subset [-1,1] \\
    \chi(0) & = 1 \\
    \psi(\mathbb R) = \chi(\mathbb R) & = [0,1]\\
    z & \in\mathbb C\\
    \tau & \in\mathbb R
\end{align*}$$

The claim is that
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \left| \frac{\mathrm d^N}{\mathrm dt^N} (t^z (1-\psi(t\tau)) \chi(t)) \right| \mathrm dt & \le C_N \int_0^\infty \left| \prod_{k=0}^{N-1} (z-k) t^{z - N} (1-\psi(t\tau)) \chi(t) \right| \\
& \qquad \qquad + \left| t^{z} \psi^{(N)}(t\tau) \tau^N \chi(t) \right| \\
& \qquad \qquad + \left| t^{z} (1-\psi(t\tau)) \chi^{(N)}(t) \right| \mathrm dt \\
& = C_N \int_0^\infty \left| \prod_{k=0}^{N-1} (z-k) \right| t^{\Re z - N} (1-\psi(t\tau))\chi(t) \\
& \qquad \qquad + t^{\Re z} |\psi^{(N)}(t\tau)| \tau^N \chi(t) \\
& \qquad \qquad + t^{\Re z} (1-\psi(t\tau)) |\chi^{(N)}(t)| \mathrm dt
\end{align*}$$

So basically that we can control
$$\int |\partial^N (uvw)| \le C_N \int |\partial^N u vw| + |u \partial^N vw| + |uv\partial^N w|$$
Wich is certainly not true in general (chose $u=v=w=x$ and $N=3$, for example)

So how can we justify that estimate in this special case?

Comment: I suppose that it matters here that $v=0$ near one endpoint of integration, while $w=0$ near the other. One can imagine using integration by parts to better arrange what gets differentiated. However, I would expect the estimate to be $$\int |\partial^N (uvw)| \le C_N \int |\partial^N u vw| + |u \partial^N vw| + |uv\partial^N w|$$ that is, with absolute values inside of the sum. Maybe this is what they meant to write? (I wanted to take a look at page 299; naturally, Google Books showed 298 and 300).

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Due to the nonnegativity of all the functions, you may arrange the absolute values as you wish as long as the $\prod$ is made nonnegative. I will put them accordingly. Note that $|t^z| = t^{\Re z}$

Comment: The functions are nonnegative, but their derivatives are another matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution with the help of [the MO Answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179048/controling-mixed-derivatives/179093#179093) provided on my cross-post.